# How can I delete "c" from the terminal input line?

Tags: python, keyboard-events

My current code is:

```
import keyboard
import create_reminders as create
import store_reminders as store

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("c"):
        reminder = input("type task")
        store.store(reminder)
        time.sleep(1)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed("r"):
        print("remove reminder")
        time.sleep(1)
```

My output after c is pressed and tidy is typed as input:
"ctidy"

The c from the terminal is held and placed at the start of my input

I have tried to add a keyboard.send("del") to simulate a delete key press but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Add `keyboard.read_key()` to read the keystroke that you KNOW is waiting.  If that's your whole code, then you are in a 100% CPU loop, and you should probably replace the `is_pressed` calls with `read_key` anyway, which blocks until a key is pressed.

Comment: Nothing about this task requires the `keyboard` library in the first place. `key = sys.stdin.read(1)` is more than enough for the use case at hand. Don't pull out libraries that use platform-specific extensions until and unless you actually _need_ those extensions.

Comment: similarly, something as `sys.stderr.write('\r \r')` might be all you need.

Comment: `keyboard` being lower-level, reading keystrokes with it doesn't consume them and make them unavailable for other kinds of I/O. Again: **Don't use `keyboard` for this**.